# Git - update line-endings without affecting the blame

Tags: git

I have a file that has the wrong line-endings. I'm wondering if there is anyway to fix them in a commit but in such a way that the blame won't show that I've modified every single line in the file. I'd really like to keep the file's line history useful.

Comment: You might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945382/git-commit-that-doesnt-override-original-authors-in-git-blame?rq=1

Comment: And I would say the *second* answer on that thread is better than the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `git blame -w ...` should do the trick based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3945497/379282).

Wonder if Github has a blame view that includes `-w`

Comment: I'm not sure about GitHub, but `git gui blame` I believe uses it by default.